# How to display the form fields of content type in a table using custom template file?

Tags: entities, theming

I have created a content type **Article** including the fields **Field 1**, **Field 2**, **Field 3** ......

All these fields have multiple values. I also created the **custom template** for this content type.

Now I want to display all fields of the form in a table and use only one button **Add another item** to add a line for all the fields.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the following snippet in **template.php** of your active theme;

```
<?php
function THEMENAME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'article_node_form' => array(
            'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
            'template' => 'node--add--article',
            'render element' => 'form',
            ),
    );
}
?>
```

Then create a template file called **node--add--article.tpl.php** (same as the 'template' field in template.php.)

This is **node--add--article.tpl.php**:

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <td><?php print drupal_render_children($form['field_1']); ?></td>
    <td><?php print drupal_render_children($form['field_2']);  ?></td>
    <td><?php print drupal_render_children($form['field_3']);  ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<?php print drupal_render_children($form);  ?>
```

Now **Clear Cache** and see the result.

Comment: If you do so, then under each field will have a button "add another item"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Css Column Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp) to distribute them as table or use the combination of modules [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) & [Panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/Panelizer) (try the first option, it might be lighter to implement).

Comment: These are just some of the data included in the content type of me. There are many other data fields displayed in different structures. Can I apply under your guidance?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your last question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [field group multiple module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_multiple)

And for displaying that as table you can add to that module [field group table module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_table)

Comment: I have tried using multiple group field module but I encountered some problems with it:
- I can not delete a row when I accidentally add another item
- When you do not enter a value for the first row, but only enter a value for the second row after submit. It will automatically push data up the second row in the first row.

Comment: - Since I created the template for the form and add the node node template should I encountered some problems with it when it displays in node node add form and template

Comment: You could try [field collection module] (https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) , the best way is to have node separated from that fields. for example you can create entity with that fields and attach it to the node using reference field and add on the top of it something like [inline entity form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form). Keep in mind field_collection is entity

Answer (score 0):

try this [Field Collection Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_table)
it work with: [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection)

Regards